# Modal Window on card click JS CSS PHP

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have 6 cards on my html. Each one on click need to pop up a modal window (this modal window is the card with more informations, so each modal window is corresponding to one card).

I dont know how to do that. After a day searching on the web I'm here to ask your help.

I have tried to make the html animal_card, and my modal appart. Then all the content will change with php.
And the Javascript need to change the modal window css property to absolute on click.

Someone know how to do that with Javascript ?

HTML :

```
<div class="animal_card">
    <div class="card_title">
        <h3>title</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="card_image">
        <img src="image.img" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="card_text">
        <div class="card_info">
            <div class="card_info_age">
                <h4>Age</h4>
                <p>14</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card_info_gender">
                <h4>Gender :</h4>
                <p>Female</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h4>Who am I</h4>
        <p>Description Text</p>
    </div>
</div> 

<div class="bg-modal">
            <div class="modal-content">

                <div class="modal-animal">
                    <h1>Animal Name</h1>
                    <button class="close" onclick="closeModal()">&times</button>
                    <div><img src="img/greciaprofile.jpg" alt=""></div>

                    <div class="animal-informations">
                        <div class="left">
                            <label for="">Age</label>
                            <p>14</p>
                            <label for="">Sexe</label>
                            <p>Female</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="right">
                            <label for="">Description</label>
                            <p>
                                Text
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <button class="main">Adopt</button>
                        <button class="secondary">Support</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS :

```
.bg-modal {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.modal-content {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 5rem;
    width: 75vw;
    background-color: $white;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```

Javascript :

```
const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.animal_card');
const modal = document.getElementsByClassName('bg-modal');

const onCardClick = async (e) => {
    const card = e.currentTarget;

    modal.style.position = 'absolute';
}

cards.forEach(card => card.addEventListener('click', onCardClick));

function closeModal() {
    modal[0].style.position = 'none';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.animal_card');
const modal = document.getElementsByClassName('bg-modal');

const getKeyMap = (modal) => {
 if (modal) {
    let i;
    let keyMap = {};
    for (i = 0; i < modal.length; i++) {
      const item = modal[i];
      const key = item.getAttribute('key');
      keyMap[key] = item;
    }
    
    return keyMap;
 }
 
 return null;
};

const modalMap = getKeyMap(modal);

const onCardClick = async (e) => {
    const card = e.currentTarget && e.currentTarget.getAttribute('key') || null;
    const selectedModal = modalMap[card] || null;
    
   if (selectedModal) {
     selectedModal.style.position = 'absolute';
   } 
}

cards.forEach(card => card.addEventListener('click', onCardClick));
```

```css
.bg-modal {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    /* position: absolute; */
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.modal-content {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 5rem;
    width: 75vw;
    background-color: $white;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div key="5" class="animal_card">
    <div class="card_title">
        <h3>title</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="card_image">
        <img src="image.img" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="card_text">
        <div class="card_info">
            <div class="card_info_age">
                <h4>Age</h4>
                <p>14</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card_info_gender">
                <h4>Gender :</h4>
                <p>Female</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h4>Who am I</h4>
        <p>Description Text</p>
    </div>
</div> 

<div class="bg-modal" key="5">
            <div class="modal-content">

                <div class="modal-animal">
                    <h1>Animal Name</h1>
                    <button class="close">&times</button>
                    <div><img src="img/greciaprofile.jpg" alt=""></div>

                    <div class="animal-informations">
                        <div class="left">
                            <label for="">Age</label>
                            <p>14</p>
                            <label for="">Sexe</label>
                            <p>Female</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="right">
                            <label for="">Description</label>
                            <p>
                                Text
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <button class="main">Adopt</button>
                        <button class="secondary">Support</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

So the direct answer using your example is `modal` on the `onCardClick` is returning a collection, not a single element. So selecting the first one `modal[0]` will fix the position update. I attached an example.

If you are going to show different modals based on the card you click on, you generally need to have a method to track them. Really depends on how you want to do that, based on ids, or index position or so on. Anyways, let me know if this helps.

Comment: ```const modal = document.getElementsByClassName('bg-modal');```

This part return a collection ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. So it will return `[modal1, modal2, modal3, ...etc]`. So in the example, since there is only one, I used `modal[0]` to get the modal you provided in the example code.

Comment: Super thank you, this work well.

So you said if I'm going to show different modals based on the card that I click on, I need a method to track them. 

The animal_card is in the same file as the modal. All the content is changing with php (exemple : the animal name is the same on the card and on the modal). I duplicate this file with php ```(for (i=0;i <6, i++) { include 'card + modal' })```

So now I have 6 cards and 6 modals. I have thinked if I add with php a id="i" to the card and to the modal I can select them like this with js. But same id not allowed. What is your way to do that ?

Comment: Updated the example ^. Used the attr `key` to link the card to modal. So, the change here was get a list of all modals, map them by key. In the example, the key is `5`. When the user clicks a card, grab the target key and match it against the modal map. If a modal exists with that key, show it, otherwise do nothing. Let me know if this makes sense or helps with your scenario.